# How to just search last 3 months in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, search

[this page](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-Outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da) does not seem to be particularly well structured nor does it appear to have a full list of usable values

Comment: This question is poorly constructed and has nothing to do with the title. Please explain what you are attempting, what you have tried and reference the link. If the link were to become broken, no one would know what you are referring to in this question.

Comment: A broken link on the internets?! gasp. Perhaps people could see where it was pointing and guess. Seems like the person who answered understood which is the main thing. I will add the word 'just' to the title. I'd add the word mail but it's a tag so...

Comment: Considering this is a community of shared information, I was thinking of the other people who may have a similar issue and read this question. Once the link breaks, the entire thing becomes irrelevant. Only trying to improve the quality of the question, not offend.  But you got what you wanted, so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a copy of OL2010 to hand, but I don't think my OL2013 should be too different.

You can use the **received** operator which is documented on that page.
But instead of using `received:=01/01/2015`, you can change the equals to a 'greater than' operator:

```
> received:>12/05/2015
```

Will find all messages which were received *after* 12th May 2015 (about 3 months ago). Note the stress on the word *after*. It will not find messages which were received *on* that date.

NB: My computer is set to UK/British regional settings, so the date format I use is dd/mm/yyyy. You might have to do it differently depending on your date settings, and how you normally do things in NZ.